# On left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment, system-verilog, quartus, synthesis

I am having trouble with combination assignment. I do not understand why I cannot use an `always` combination structure to set my output variables. When I use `assign`, I do not get the assignment error.

I thought `assign` and `always@(*)` both mean blocking (combinational assignment).

```
module control_unit(input wire [31:0] instruction
                   ,output wire RegDst
                   ,output wire ALUSrc
                   ,output wire RegWrite
                   ,output wire MemRead
                   ,output wire MemWrite
                   ,output wire MemToReg
                   ,output wire Branch
                   );

   wire [5:0] opcode;

   assign opcode  = instruction[31:26];

   always@(*) begin
      case(opcode)
            6'b000000: begin              // r-type
               RegDst   = 1'b1;
               ALUSrc   = 1'b0;
               RegWrite = 1'b1;
               MemRead  = 1'b0;
               MemWrite = 1'b0;
               MemToReg = 1'b0;
               Branch   = 1'b0;
            end
           .
           .
           .                    
            default: begin
               RegDst   = 1'b0;
               ALUSrc   = 1'b0;
               RegWrite = 1'b0;
               MemRead  = 1'b0;
               MemWrite = 1'b0;
               MemToReg = 1'b0;
               Branch   = 1'b0;
            end
      endcase
   end // end always_comb
endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot make a procedural assignment to a `wire`.  You must make a procedural assignment to a `reg`, regardless of whether the `always` block describes sequential or combinational logic.  Use the following port declarations:

```
               ,output reg RegDst
               ,output reg ALUSrc
               ,output reg RegWrite
               ,output reg MemRead
               ,output reg MemWrite
               ,output reg MemToReg
               ,output reg Branch
```

Comment: I am a little confused on the difference between a wire and a reg. From my understanding, wire is used to connect input and output ports while reg is used to store information? When why does output needs to be a reg?

Comment: Is that due to semantics? Or is there a hardware reason for it?

Comment: @Jack " wire is used to connect input and output ports while reg is used to store information". No - that is completely wrong. The difference is subtle, but you do need to understand the difference. A comment is too short to explain.

Comment: @Jack: it's mostly semantics, although the simulator has some underlying differences in how it treats the two.  In SystemVerilog both wire and reg can be replaced by "logic", similar to VHDL.